# C++ Reading ints as unsigned chars using istringstream

Tags: c++, file-io, casting, unsigned-char, istringstream

When using `std::istringstream` to read gray pixel values from a file (0-255), I notice a strange behavior and I can't understand what is happening.

To conserve memory, I want to read these values into unsigned chars (since they have the same 0-255 range). However, there appears to be some sort of casting/truncation going on.

Input file:

```
194
194
155
155
124
194
```

Here is my code:

```
getline(fp, line); 
unsigned char temp;
istringstream iss(line);
iss >> temp;
```

When the value in the file is `194`, for instance, the integer value for temp is `49`...

What type of casting is going on?

Comment: You may use unformatted input: `std::istream::get` for bytes.

Comment: The question isn't to fix the code, it's what type of casting/truncation is occurring?

Comment: Please be clearer as to your input data. At the moment we can only _guess_ at its format, because "read values from a file" tells us effectively nothing! My guess is space-delimited numbers in the range 0<=x<=255 in human-readable decimal via ASCII.

Comment: /OT @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seems I'm getting old and lame ;-) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no casting, this behavior is due to overloading.

[`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) happens to be overloaded for `char` types, extracting only one character at a time - `1`, ASCII value of which is `49`. This is the behavior you want, when you're reading single characters and it's assumed, that you want exactly that, when you're extracting to a character type.

To read the text as whitespace-delimited numbers, you have to use a larger type for the extraction e.g. `unsigned short` or `std::uint16_t` and then cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: You might as well check whether the value is in the range of `unsigned char` before the cast.

Comment: Casting to `unsigned char` is well-defined so there's no need to do a check, unless you want to have special handling for unexpected values

Comment: I meant you'd want to handle the case that you read `257` for example, and end up with `1`.